# Method in three.js to orthographically display a slice of the scene

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

I have a fairly simple scene rendered using three.js. I am trying to render just a slice of the scene, like an MRI would do.

I have made two versions of the scene for testing purposes.

1. A perspective version, this is working great
2. An orthographic version which should be only a slice of the scene on a given plane

Rendering the orthographic scene is no problem. I have tried to use the clipping plane to capture the slice, but can't get it to work. Either I get a completely white screen or the whole model.

Here is a top-down view of what I am hoping to achieve:

```
100 *----------------------------------*
    |                                  |
    |                                  |
    |                                  |
    |                                  |
    ####################################  <-- Capture this slice of 100 units width
    |                                  |
    |                                  |
    |                                  |
    |                                  |
 0  *----------------------------------*
    0                                  100





                    \  /
                     \/
                   CAMERA roughly @ (50, -100)
```

It is entirely possible that I am missing something obvious. My 3D background is decent, but I'm not an expert.

What is the best way to go about this in Three.js / WebGL? What is the best place for the camera to go?

PS: Yes, I am aware that slicing through some primitives will not work well. I am using a model built from lines and points which I expect will slice fairly safely. Cutting objects in half is not too much of an issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turned out to be the camera placement. It was obvious in hindsight that the camera should not be set back from the scene as is needed for the perspective projection. Placing the camera right at the edge of the model did the trick and the clipping plane (near, far) worked properly.

eg:

```
    Z
100 *----------------------------------*
    |                                  |
    |                                  |
75  |                                  |
    |                                  |
    |                                  |
50  |                                  |
    |                                  |
    |                                  |
25  ####################################  <-- Capture this slice of 5 units
    |                                  |      width @ z = 25
    |                                  |
 0  *-----------------X----------------* Y
    0                 .                100
                      .
                      .
                   CAMERA is here at (50,0)
                   near = 25
                   far  = 30 (for width 5, ie: 25 + 5)
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this in action? I'd be really interested in the results! Cheers